# Google maps marker not working on iphone

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari, iphone

The Google map info window will not appear when I click on a marker using the iphone.  The same code works on the desktop on Android.

I need the map hidden by default and then loaded in only when the user clicks the view map button as I want to keep the weight of the page down as this is for a mobile site.

The click event handler is being fired as I put an alert on it and it worked.  I think it might be something to do with the order of the code when I attacked the click handlers, but thats a guess.  Also, when I add draggable: true to the markers the bubble appears but I dont want the markers to be draggable.

I have set up a test page http://www.clawg.co.uk/nearby/testmap.html

A run through of this is:

- I scan the DOM for

  data attributes values which I use to create an array of data that will be used for info windows.

  I create a button on the fly that will make the map appear when clicked

  When the button is clicked the map api is loaded in if its not already available

  The map is then loaded

  The markers are positioned on the map

Comment: Forwarded by [Cameron Drake](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1971272/cameron-drake): [Here is another SO answer that may solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41053789/1971272).

Answer (score 0):

The default marker icons are too small for iphone 4 making them unclickable, so I used a custom marker that was 42x42 in size.