# Disable Gmaps dragging, enable page swipe?

Tags: html, css, google-maps, drag, swipe

I've disabled dragging on my Google Maps component, here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qr2BJ/7053/

However when I'm browsing on my iPhone I can't swipe down "on" the map. So, when the map is taking up most of the screen, mobile users won't be able to swipe (scroll) down to view the rest of the page.

Is there a way to fix this, apart from sticking an extra empty div on top of Google Maps?

Comment: Actually, whenever a user swipes on the map, its actually registered as he is trying to "drag" the map, which obviously your code does not allow. Therefore, your page is not scrolling I think an empty div is the only solution.

Comment: Also, please paste your code here rather than on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on android devices. As they are running on webkit I guess the cause is the same as for iphone. Anyways, a post on the following link addressed the issue and the first answer worked for me: [Embed Google Maps on page without overriding iPhone scroll behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534888/embed-google-maps-on-page-without-overriding-iphone-scroll-behavior)