# Google maps iframe disable scrolling touch on mobile

Tags: google-maps, mobile, iframe

Can I deactivate the google maps iframe when i'm on a mobile device?

Settings are already with **scrolling=no**, but when I scroll on mobile the map is activated and become active.

Is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534888/embed-google-maps-on-page-without-overriding-iphone-scroll-behavior

Comment: Thanks, how I can use this in a iframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and used something like this:

```
<style>
  .overlay {
    background:transparent; 
    position:relative; 
    width:640px
    height:480px; 
    top:480px; 
    margin-top:-480px;}
</style>

<html>
  <div class="overlay" onClick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
  <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=some_map_id" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
</html>
```

The div covers the map, preventing pointer events from getting to it. If you click on the div, it becomes transparent to pointer events, activating the map.