# Google maps touch scroll not working on Windows Phone

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, windows-phone, gestures

My web application lets users create new location based trips. There is a google maps map displaying the current location they've entered in a form.

I've read in [this post about touch scrolling and google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534888/embed-google-maps-on-page-without-overriding-iphone-scroll-behavior) that most of touch scrolling is ok with this code:

```
var dragFlag = false;
var start = 0, end = 0;

$('#maps-map').on('touchstart', function(e) {
  console.log('Starting!');
  dragFlag = true;
  start = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
});

$('#maps-map').on('touchmove', function(e) {
  console.log('Moving!');
  if ( !dragFlag ) return;
  end = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  window.scrollBy( 0,( start - end ) );
});

$('#maps-map').on('touchend', function(e) {
  console.log('Ending');
  dragFlag = false;
});
```

And of course, google maps has to be added to following container:

```
<div id="#maps-map"></div>
```

Now if I test this on my HTC-device, in my console I get:

```
'Starting!'
'Moving!'
'Moving!'
'Ending!'
```

But if I watch my console when debugging my Nokia Lumnia device (emulated) i get nothing.

Jquery [states](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/1.4/) that is has support for this device. What could be the cause of not doing this intuïtive touch gestures?

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile framework?

Comment: Yes, I've included the jquery mobile touch events: "Touch events including: touchstart, touchmove, touchend, tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft, swiperight, scrollstart, scrollstop"

Comment: `#maps-map` is map canvas or div wrapping canvas?

Comment: var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps-map'), mapOptions); -> It's the wrapping canvas